# PrimeNG Datatable change detection strategy onPush does not work

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using primeng angular datatable. I am trying to use onPush change detection strategy but it does not seem to work. Table keeps updating before I call `cd.detectChanges();`. This leads me to serious performance problems as the table becomes unresponsive

Comment: Could you tell us how you tried to do it? I think that primeNG does not directly support this option in its components.

Comment: I have a component and I added the primeng datatable there. On this parent component I set the changeDetectionStrategy to onPush. Although I dont call ChangeDetector.detectChanges() and I update the data table is being updated whereas it shouldn't

Comment: Have you tried to completely detach the change detection using https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detach or you only set ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush? If not please try to detach() and then if the table still updates, it could mean that primeNG tables are independent of the Angular DI system.